# Extract Substring from text in SQL sever

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, substring

I capture MDX statements fired on the SSAS Cube using a SQL profiler into a table. What I want to do is to extract the Cube name from the MDX statement.

The problem I have is the fact that the MDX statements are pretty huge and random (Users connect to the Cube and create Adhoc reports) and have multiple Sub Cubes constructed making it difficult to fetch the Cube Name.

I was able to figure out a pattern for search.

```
First string: 'FROM ['
Second string: ']'
```

I need to now pickup a substring from the variable.
Example below:

```
DECLARE @TEXT varchar(max) = 'SELECT NON EMPTY ((((  [[ XXXXX  ]] }) ON ROWS  FROM (SELECT ({XXXXXXXX }) ON COLUMNS  FROM [Sales Reporting])) 
WHERE XXXXX ))'

DECLARE @FirstPosition int = (SELECT CHARINDEX('FROM [',@TEXT)+5)
DECLARE @SecondPosition int = (SELECT CHARINDEX(']',@TEXT,@FirstPosition))

SELECT @FirstPosition, @SecondPosition

SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('FROM [',@TEXT)+5,(CHARINDEX(']',@TEXT,@FirstPosition)-CHARINDEX('[',@TEXT))-1)
```

Desired Result = Sales Reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution turned out to be simple than I expected.

```
DECLARE @TEXT varchar(max) = 'SELECT NON EMPTY ((((  [[ XXXXX  ]] }) ON ROWS  FROM (SELECT ({XXXXXXXX }) ON COLUMNS  FROM [Sales Reporting])) 
WHERE XXXXX ))'

DECLARE @FirstPosition int = (SELECT CHARINDEX('FROM [',@TEXT)+5)
DECLARE @ExtractString nvarchar(max) = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXT,@FirstPosition, LEN(@Text)))
DECLARE @SecondPosition int = (SELECT CHARINDEX(']',@ExtractString))

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ExtractString,CHARINDEX('[',@ExtractString)+1,(CHARINDEX(']',@ExtractString)-CHARINDEX('[',@ExtractString))-1) AS CubeName
```